# Restful Web services run on localhost apache tomcat, how to access from other computer over internet

Tags: java, android, web-services, tomcat

I have a scenario

1. Rest web app(using spring framework) running on localhost(on web server Apache Tomcat 8 on window 10), pc is connected to internet
2. Another person 2oo km away from me, wants to hit my web services using postman or android app.

This is my servel.xml of tomcat -

```
   <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
  <Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
 <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
-->
 <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
<!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
<Listener  className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

<!-- Global JNDI resources
   Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
-->
<GlobalNamingResources>
<!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
     UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
-->
<Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
          type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
          description="User database that can be updated and saved"
          factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
          pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
</GlobalNamingResources>

<!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share
   a single "Container" Note:  A "Service" is not itself a "Container",
   so you may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
   Documentation at /docs/config/service.html
 -->
<Service name="Catalina">

<!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
<!--
<Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
    maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
-->


<!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
     and responses are returned. Documentation at :
     Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
     Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
     APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
     Define a non-SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
-->
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
<!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
<!--
<Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
           port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
-->
<!-- Define a SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
     This connector uses the NIO implementation that requires the JSSE
     style configuration. When using the APR/native implementation, the
     OpenSSL style configuration is required as described in the APR/native
     documentation -->
<!--
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
-->

<!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />


<!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
     every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
     analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
     on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
     Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

<!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">
-->
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

  <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
      /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
      /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
  <!--
  <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
  -->

  <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
       via a brute-force attack -->
  <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
    <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
         resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
         that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
         available for use by the Realm.  -->
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
           resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
  </Realm>

  <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

    <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
         Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
    <!--
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
    -->

    <!-- Access log processes all example.
         Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
         Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
           prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
           pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

  </Host>
</Engine>
```

How to achieve this ?

Comment: your public IP which in this case (your ISP's public IP address) must be configured to have it's TCP port ( defaulted to port 80 for HTTP) open for receiving all incoming traffic from anywhere (address binding to 0.0.0.0).

Comment: how to change the port binding

Comment: i'm not sure how you're starting your tomcat server.. if you're configuring tomcat with `server.xml` then you should change connector port IP address `127.0.0.1` to `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: yeah I get the server.xml in config folder

Comment: <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />

Answer (score 0):

```
Open ports to your router
```

[Open Port](http://www.wikihow.com/Open-Ports)

```
Then search on google "What is my public IP"
If your public ip  is 127.0.0.1
tomcat port is 8080 and opened port is 8080 and war name is abc
then 127.0.0.1:8080/abc is accessible on internet
```